# JSONDecoder does not throw when JSON doesn't match data structure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, decodable

The JSONDecoder.decode method doesn't throw error when the incoming JSON doesn't match the data type.

I have a data model like this that maps the JSON to a user profile:

```
struct DrivetimeUserProfile: Codable {

    var driverId: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var city: String?
    var state: String?
    var experience: Int?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case driverId = "driver_id"
        case name = "name"
        case email = "email"
        case phoneNumber = "phone"
        case city = "city"
        case state = "state"
        case experience = "experience"

    }
}
```

When the username or password is incorrect, the server will return a JSON like this `\"Failure\":\"Enter correct username and password.\"`. Which doesn't map to the user profile data model and the JSONDecoder().decode doesn't throw an error

Here is the full implementation:

```
func loginUser(from url: URL, with username: String, and password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let query = "email=\(username)&password=\(password)"
        request.httpBody = query.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(nil, .EmptyData)
                return
            }

            do {
                let userProfile = try JSONDecoder().decode(DrivetimeUserProfile.self, from: data)
                self.userProfile = userProfile

                completionHandler(userProfile, nil)

            } catch (let error) {

                completionHandler(nil, .CannotDecodeJson)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I need this completion handler to capture the thrown error so I can alert the user in my view controller of what the error is. Please advice

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That's the huge disadvantage if you declare all struct members thoughtlessly as optional.

If the key does not exist in the struct all members are set to `nil` and no error is thrown.

Comment: What would be the remedy?

Comment: Remove the question marks then you'll get the error. Or add an optional `Failure` member